# How to use reduxForm() and connect() together for class component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

added reducer in reducer file

```
const reducers = {
  // ... other reducers here ...
  form: formReducer
};
```

I am using [`redux-form`](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/) v 7.1.2 with react v 16 and using ``` reduxForm()`` but there is already ```connect()` applied in this class, tried 2 approached to add both HOC in the same page but failed on both.

below is the relevant code of my files , please check and let me know what  is missing ?

1. Using named export

#### renderField.jsx

```
    import React from 'react';

    const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
          <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
          {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    export default renderField;
```

#### Register.jsx

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { renderField } from './renderField';

class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: ''
            },
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    handleSubmit (values) {
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { user } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(userActions.register(user));
    }

    render () {
        const { registering } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Field
                            name="firstName"
                            type="text"
                            label="First Name"
                            className="form-control"
                            component={renderField}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={this.pristine} >Register</button>
                        { registering && <Loading /> }
                        <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

below class definition , here is connect and reduxForm usage

```
RegisterPage = reduxForm({
    form: 'register',
    destroyOnUnmount: false
})(RegisterPage);

const connectedRegisterPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterPage);

export { connectedRegisterPage as RegisterPage };
```

#### App.jsx

```
import { RegisterPage } from '../RegisterPage';

<Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
```

BUT this gives multiple warning in console

> Failed prop type: The prop `component` is marked as required in
>   `Field`, but its value is `undefined`. in Field (created by
>   RegisterPage)
>
> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `ConnectedField`.

---

2. with default export

#### Register.jsx

```
RegisterPage = reduxForm({
    form: 'register'
})(RegisterPage);

const connectedRegisterPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterPage);

export { connectedRegisterPage as default };
```

#### App.jsx

```
import RegisterPage from '../RegisterPage';
console.log("RegisterPage", RegisterPage); // undefined
```

this gives no warning but display blank page in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exported `renderField` as a `default` and `imported as a named import`. Correct it and it should work fine

```
import React from 'react';

    const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
          <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
          {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    export {renderField};
```

Comment: oh my luck. Thanks for pointing, I have changed in *RegisterPage.jsx* as `import renderField from ./` but still now displaying anything in the URL

Comment: Can you try and log registerField in the RegisterPage component and see if you get the correct component. My guess is that the path may be incorrect

Comment: yes I have logged that using console.log(RegisterPage) and it outputs function body `function Connect(ReduxForm)()`

Comment: No not `console.log(RegisterPage)` but `console.log(renderField)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159551/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-shubham-khatri).